# Make a temp network

Tags: wifi, xampp

I have a XAMPP test server running on my Windows Vista laptop.  I also have a small wireless router. I would like be able to create a small temp network that could broadcast that network so any other computers connected to the wifi can go to `localhost/` or an internal ip address and view my server. The router will not be able to be connected to the internet, but I don't see how that would make a difference

Thanks
giodamelio

Comment: You've got the server, got the wireless router and network, computer connecting.... sound like everything's working. What's the question??

Comment: Sorry if this is and extremely noobish question. I don't know about the hardware part either. Do I connect the router to the laptop via cat5? Do i need to configure the server to make other computers be able to see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect your laptop to one of the LAN ports on your router (if they're unmarked, you'll usually have a group of four ports together and one a little separate. you want one of the four).

If you're running a firewall on your laptop, you'll need to open a port for your server. In Windows Firewall this can be done from the Control Panel.

To access your server other clients on the wifi can just type your laptop's name into their address bars with the port number specified. Your IP will also work.

Comment: When I visit 192.168.1.2(my laptops internal ip) i see my server home page, but when i go to 192.168.1.2 from my iPhone connected to my wifi network it wont load.

Comment: Silly fix, turns out i had my laptops ip address wrong :(. Thanks again.